# Convert a json format into a structured dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas:

```
results = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()

results

{‘ABC: {’26/03/2021': {‘A’: ‘1234’,
  ‘B’: ‘5678’},
 '29/03/2021': {‘A’: ‘5555’,
  ‘B’: ‘6666’},
 '30/03/2021': {‘A’: '44779',
  ‘B’: '10364'} }
```

And would you like to convert this dataframe?

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 26/03/2021 | 1234 | 5678 |
| ABC | 29/03/2021 | 5555 | 6666 |
| ABC | 30/03/2021 | 44779 | 10364 |

Could you help me find a way out of this?

Comment: can you read the data trough read_json and see how it looks like ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try (`results` is your dictionary from the question):

```py
all_data = []
for k, v in results.items():
    for kk, vv in v.items():
        all_data.append({"COLUMN1": k, "COLUMN2": kk, **vv})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  COLUMN1     COLUMN2      A      B
0     ABC  26/03/2021   1234   5678
1     ABC  29/03/2021   5555   6666
2     ABC  30/03/2021  44779  10364
```

Prints: